# SQL search query not showing correct result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure which searches employees from the table employee.

My query looks like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EmployeeList]
    @CurrentPageNo INT = null,
    @PageSize INT = 5,
    @FirstName VARCHAR(100),
    @Email VARCHAR(100),
    @DeptId int = null
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StartRecordNo INT, @EndRecordNo INT

    IF @CurrentPageNo IS NULL
        SET @CurrentPageNo = 1

    SET @StartRecordNo = ((@CurrentPageNo - 1) * @PageSize)
    SET @EndRecordNo = @StartRecordNo + @PageSize

    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CreatedByDate desc) As srno,
        EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, Email, DateOfBirth, Joining, 
        MobileNumber, MonthsOfExperience, TotalExperience, DepartmentName 
    FROM
        Employee
    INNER JOIN
        Department ON Employee.DeptId = Department.DepartmentID
    WHERE   
        (ISNULL(@FirstName, '') = '' OR Employee.FirstName LIKE '%' + FirstName + '%') 
        AND 
        (ISNULL(@Email, '') = '' OR Employee.Email LIKE '%' + @Email + '%')  
        AND
        (@DeptId IS NULL OR Employee.DeptId = @DeptId)
END
```

The procedure is compiled successfully. but when execute it like

```
exec EmployeeList 1,10,'shaili','',null
```

It shows other records too. Can anyone explain this? I want only the record with the given name.

Result I got:

[image: Executed query]

Comment: In the where close just try to find only by FirstName.

Comment: Remove "%" . the proc give you all the names containe 'sh' here.

Comment: @Lasith Did that by commenting two other lines. I searched by the name VIKAS and still shows all three results. Am I missing some logic.

Comment: @Sami and what if i searched with vikas. still showing the same result.

Comment: Problem is with or clause  OR only evaluates expressions until it find a TRUE result

Comment: by passing '' as value for email you have (ISNULL(@Email, '') = '' OR Employee.Email LIKE '%%') and I think that might just return more records than you desired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Siddhant only little mistake by you. i.e you pass FirstName instead of @FirstName. check below code.

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test_EmployeeList]
        @CurrentPageNo INT = null,
        @PageSize INT=5,
        @FirstName VARCHAR(100),
        @Email VARCHAR(100),
        @DeptId int = null

    AS
    BEGIN
     DECLARE @StartRecordNo INT,@EndRecordNo INT

     IF @CurrentPageNo IS NULL
        SET @CurrentPageNo=1

    SET @StartRecordNo=((@CurrentPageNo-1) * @PageSize)
    SET @EndRecordNo=@StartRecordNo + @PageSize
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Reg_Date desc) As srno,
     F_Name, L_Name, Email, Mobile, Reg_Date from tbl_LoginMaster
    inner join tbl_Login_Detail
    ON tbl_LoginMaster.User_Id = tbl_Login_Detail.User_Id


    WHERE   (ISNULL(@FirstName,'')='' OR tbl_LoginMaster.F_Name LIKE '%'+@FirstName+'%') AND 
        (ISNULL(@Email,'')='' OR tbl_LoginMaster.Email LIKE '%'+@Email+'%') AND
        (@DeptId is null OR tbl_LoginMaster.User_Id = @DeptId )
    END
    GO


    exec Test_EmployeeList 1,10,'Mohit','',null
```